# MySql data into html table

Tags: php, mysql, html

Please, good people, I must ask you for help. To use with chart I must generate HTML table with data from MySQL. I'm now in point after sql `SELECT`.
The table structure must be as

```
<div class="clean">
    <table id='myTableClean'>
        <caption>Game players count</caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Jan</th>
                <th>Feb</th>
                <th>Mar</th>
                <th>Apr</th>
                <th>May</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>2010</th>
                <td>125</td>
                <td>185</td>
                <td>327</td>
                <td>359</td>
                <td>376</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>2009</th>
                <td>1167</td>
                <td>1110</td>
                <td>691</td>
                <td>165</td>
                <td>135</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

All info is from db: months, years and points. And I don't know how much cells will be.

My problem is to generate table with `THREAD` section, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: What's your select statement? What did you already try?

Comment: I try to display data witch I received from sql querry. $month, $year, $points.

Comment: Please read [Writing the perfect question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints). Particularly **The Golden Rule: Imagine You're Trying To Answer The Question**

Comment: @Herbert - all necessary info was embodies into post. Maybe read before write. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @Andrew: You added your code AFTER I made my comment. If all necessary info was in the post you wouldn't have so many comments asking you what you're talking about. Your question has improved since I made that comment.

Comment: @Herbert - All basic data were provided from the beginning. And if someone asks a question - do not understand the problem or the question was poorly worded. Anyway - you're right and I was calm. brgs

Comment: Okay, you edited your question (which is fine btw) and then you called me out with the statement "Maybe read before write." Now your question is back to what you started with which doesn't contain enough info for us to help you.

Comment: @Herbert Sorry, "read before write' referred to the fact that you simply had no arguments. I withdrew my edits so that the question now is simple and clear. As from the beginning. I wanted good - came out badly, as in life. brgs

Answer (score 2):

as i understand, here is the basic structure, you can implement it with you database cause you didn't show you database structure in you question..

```
$query = "select * from tbl_name";
$result = mysql_query($query);

echo '<table>';
echo '<thead>';
echo '<tr>';
  echo '<th></th>';
  echo '<th>Jan</th>';
  echo '<th>Feb</th>';
  echo '<th>March</th>';
  echo '<th>April</th>';
  echo '<th>May</th>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '</thead>';

while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo '<tr>';

    echo '<th>column_name</th>
    <td>column_name</td>
    <td>column_name</td>
    <td>column_name</td>
    <td>column_name</td>
    <td>column_name</td>';

    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Maybe you should add the `<tbody>` to your solution so that it matches the needed table structure. (I guess he wants `<tbody>` as well when he is expecting a `<thead>`)

Comment: @fix_moeller, in my answer i said 'the basic structure' that can easily changed according to askers requirement,

Comment: As I wrote - all $data are from database so you can't read "months" before "while('. If you can - show me how :). thnks

Comment: @Andrew, Please don't mind, but you should have to write all the problems in your question, cause as i see you edited you question more then 3 or 4 times and you should have to mention your edited part,,

Comment: @jogesh_p - is editing wrong thing? I add some info couse it more better explain the problem or tell the solution. But the sorce is from the basic question - all useful infos, as I think. I don't add any news. thnks for your comment, brgs

Comment: @Andrew, editing is not the wrong thing buddy, but you should have to edit like this 'EDIT: edited information here'

Comment: @jogesh_p - of course, you are right. Thank you for your hint. brgs

Comment: I was thinking that maybe is needed to display the same month, then group the results of years and them building the expected table structure.